# Trying to removed unused imports with a pre-commit hook but imports that are being used are getting removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backbone.js, eslint, lint-staged

I just installed `eslint-plugin-unused-imports`. When I commit, it does all its linting work and removed a bunch of imports even though many of those imports are being used in the file.

May or may not be worth noting, this project has a bunch of legacy Backbone and newer React components, with some Backbone views rendering React components. Also, this is a JS not TS project.

eslint-plugin-unused-imports issues states:

https://github.com/sweepline/eslint-plugin-unused-imports/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=

> If the issue is with something being marked wrongly as a unused import
> and therefore being removed. It is an issue with the imported package
> (`@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` for TS or `eslint` for JS) and its
> `no-unused-vars` rule. I cannot do anything about this except updating
> if a fix is made upstream.
>
> If new rules are added `no-unused-vars` upstream which should be
> autofixed, mark your issue *rule addition*.

But I'm not sure how to address this.

Below is my linting setup:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^1.1.0",
    ...
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "prettier-stylelint": "^0.4.2",
    ...
    "stylelint": "^9.8.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.0.0",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^1.1.2",
    ...
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "eslint": ">=6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": ">=2.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": ">=9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": ">=4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": ">=4.0.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,json,jsx,scss}": [
      "node ./scripts/lint-prettier.js"
    ],
    "*.{js,jsx,json,md}": [
      "prettier --list-different"
    ]
  },
  ...
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged && npm test"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that it is not strictly related to your question but, have you considered the `--fix` option instead?

Comment: You can also consider ditching this eslint rule and handling it via `unimported` in a CI pipeline